# Need help for homework about function and pointers

Tags: c++, function

Asume that f() returns a reference to an integer (`int & f();`), `f()+=5;` and `f()=f()+5;` are different, explain how and give pesudo code for f() to illustrate this difference.

If p is an `int *p`, what is the difference between, these two statement in C++:

```
if (p!=NULL && *p !=0).... 
if (*p !=0 && p !=NULL)....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f()+=5` could be different from `f()`=`f()`+5 if `f()` returned a reference to a different integer at each call. This could only happen if `f()` read from some global variable which was different each time that it was called.

The difference between `if (p!=NULL && *p !=0)` and `if (*p !=0 && *p !=NULL)` is that the first one checks whether `p` is null and then checks whether the `int` that `p` points to is `0` . The second one only checks whether the `int` that `p` points to is `0` (and performs this check twice).

Comment: It is worthwhile to mention that in first case `p!=NULL` will always be evaluated first and if the result is `false`, `*p != 0` will not be executed at all.(i.e pointer will be dereferenced only if it is not `NULL`)This short circuiting is guaranteed by the standard & hence the first case is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Als: Well -- it is guaranteed to work as long as `p` points to a valid object or is null. The second one is only guaranteed to work if `p` points to a valid object.

Comment: the second question was a typo it is actually, if (p!=NULL && *p !=0).... 
if (*p !=0 && p !=NULL).... Now what is the difference guys?

Comment: @catvsrat: Changing `*p !=0 && *p !=NULL` to `*p !=0 && p !=NULL` does not change its meaning _at all_. It is still an expression which requires `p!=NULL`, and which contains a subexpression which is redundant (`*p!=NULL` and `p!=NULL` will both *always* evaluate to true if `*p!=0` evaluates to true (in all cases that the expression has defined behaviour), so you effectively have `&& true`, which adds nothing of value to the expression).

Answer (score 2):

In the first, you can have `f()` declare two static variables and a static pointer to one of them.

Then return them alternately for each call, something like (pseudo-code since it's homework):

```
def f():
    static var1 = 0;
    static var2 = 42;
    static pointer curr_var = reference of var1
    if curr_var == reference of var1:
        curr_var = reference of var2
    else:
        curr_var = reference of var1
    return curr_var
```

or, even worse:

```
def f():
    static var1 = array[1024];
    static idx = -1;
    idx = (idx + 1) % 100
    return reference of var1[idx]
```

For your second question, the hint is the difference between `*p` and `p`. For example, I wouldn't use the second one in the case where `p` itself could be NULL.